Only one of 2 JavaScript animations work at a time
I have a responsive website and I need 2 different JavaScript translations under 2 different script tags to run depending on @media but only one translation will run at a time while the other does absolutely nothing. Im not sure how to make them both work with each other or how to make one run if a certain @media is true.
The "navigation scroll" should run for every device except for mobile (as the navigation will not be displayed on mobile). The "cta scroll" should run for mobile devices (This button will be visible with all device widths but it should only translate on mobile).
The header button will be displayed on all screen widths but I only want the "cta scroll" to take place when the device width is under 450px
The javascript if statments only worked if one of the script tags were deleted.
I tried merging the two script tags into the same if statement. I tried using window.matchMedia().I may have done these incorrectly. The only thing that partially worked was deleting one of the script tags.
Here is my code:

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Whimsicss Studio - Websites for Small Businesses</title>

</head>
<body>
<header style="height:1000px;">
<nav id="navigation" style="position: fixed; top:0; width:100%; height:70px; background-color: grey; transition: .8s;">

</nav>
<script> /*navigation scroll*/
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
function scrollFunction() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
document.getElementById("navigation").style.top = "0";
                 
} else {
document.getElementById("navigation").style.top = "-90px";
}
prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
</script>

<section style="margin-top: 90px;">
<h1>
Websites are more than design, they’re a part of a Strategy
</h1>
<a href="contact.html" class="button" id="header-button" style="display:block; position:fixed; bottom:30vh; background-color:skyblue; width:100px; height:50px; border:2px solid red; transition: 0.8s ease-in-out">
Lets Talk!
</a>
        
<script> /* cta scroll*/
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
function scrollFunction() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
document.getElementById("header-button").style.left = "0.25in";
} else {
document.getElementById("header-button").style.left = "-10in";
prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
}
</script>
</section>  
            
</header>
        
</body>
</html>




You should use CSS media queries for setting CSS properties (such as transition) depending on media's width.

Prefer not to use inline styles.

Do not change style properties directly. Toggle a .class with the required properties instead.


Example, an element which has transition only on mobile:
#element {
  transition: 0.8s;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #element {
    transition: none;
  }
}

Since I'm not sure which animations to make for your example, I'll provide an example of my own, hoping it will be efficient.


document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    btn.classList.toggle("animated");
  })
})
.btn {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn.animated {
  top: 100px;
}

.btn-mobile {
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.btn-desktop {
  transition: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .btn-mobile {
    transition: none;
  }
  .btn-desktop {
    transition: 0.8s;
  }
}
<button class="btn btn-mobile">animated on mobile</button>
<button class="btn btn-desktop">animated on desktop</button>




This is a dumbed down version of my code. In the original file I have media queries and separate css files. I apologize for not formatting it correctly here. Quite frankly this is my first post. To clarify the animation a little, I want the JavaScript to translate the cta (header) button only on mobile devices. If the device width is greater than 450px than I wont want the button to move at all. the animation should be activated when the page scolls. scrolling down will make the button/navigation disappear and scrolling up should make it reappear, both with sliding animations. Thank you!

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try first to improve your code according to my suggestions as it is part of the solution. This site is about getting answers, not work done for you.
